# SQL Server 2008 - concatenate group from subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query below yields these two rows (lastinspectionid, pastduereccount):

```
F5EF6588-4128-47D8-B185-002E9889D87A, htmlfromqueryrow1 
F5EF6588-4128-47D8-B185-002E9889D87A, htmlfromqueryrow2
```

I want to roll these into a single row with the pastduereccount columns concatenated.

Cannot seem to get stuff for xml to work with a subquery like below.

```
select lastinspectionid, PastDueRecCount2 = stuff((select ' ' + PastDueRecCount for xml path('')),1,1,'')
from
(
select lastinspectionid,   '<span style=''padding:3px;background-color:' + rowcolor + '''>' + convert(nvarchar(10),count(lastinspectionid)) + '</span>' as PastDueRecCount 
                        from
                        (
                            select [LastInspectionID], rowcolor =  case when DATEDIFF(day,[DueDate],getdate()) < 0 then '#FFCE8A' when DATEDIFF(day,[DueDate],getdate()) > 0 then '#FFA6A6'  end 
                            FROM
                            [dbo].[ReferenceRecommendations] 
                            group by [LastInspectionID],[DueDate] HAVING Count(DATEDIFF(day,[DueDate],getdate())) > -7
                        ) a
                        where rowcolor is not null
                        group by lastinspectionid, rowcolor

) as b group by lastInspectionID
```

Comment: You don't even have STUFF or FOR XML in your query. The answer to your question can be found here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thank you Sean Lange for this helpful tip.  However, I am trying to get STUFF FOR XML to work for the above query so that the two rows return a single row with the pastduereccount columns concatenated, as I clearly spell out above.

Comment: Right you said that. But it doesn't look like you have tried. And when I try to run this on my database I get object not found. I can't help you because you haven't shared enough information for others to help.

Comment: @nerdperson Please post your attempt to use STUFF FOR XML, and what error you got so we can help debug your attempt.   Why do you say your query as currently posted yields two rows, when it clearly must result in two columns?

Comment: posted stuff for xml

Answer (score 0):

cte works however can't use cte in subquery:

```
with cte1 as
(
select lastinspectionid, '<span style=''padding:3px;background-color:' + rowcolor + '''>' + convert(nvarchar(10),count(lastinspectionid)) + '</span>' as PastDueRecCount 
                        from
                        (
                            select [LastInspectionID], rowcolor =  case when DATEDIFF(day,[DueDate],getdate()) < 0 then '#FFCE8A' when DATEDIFF(day,[DueDate],getdate()) > 0 then '#FFA6A6'  end 
                            FROM
                            [dbo].[ReferenceRecommendations] 
                            group by [LastInspectionID],[DueDate] HAVING Count(DATEDIFF(day,[DueDate],getdate())) > -7
                        ) as a
                        where rowcolor is not null
                        group by lastinspectionid, rowcolor
 )  
 select
lastinspectionid,stuff((select' ' + PastDueRecCount from cte1 b where cte1.LastInspectionID = b.LastInspectionID for xml path('')),1,1,'')
from
 cte1 group by LastInspectionID
```